# When I enter sculpt mode my model's hair looks deformed

Tags: sculpting, hair

I have tried making a choppy haircut for my character, so that the hair ends flat (like a cartoon character) rather than at a point.

I started out with a cube, made it thinner and curved it to fix onto the head of my model. I was happy with the shape but I wanted to give it a little texture with the sculpt tool.

However, when I changed it to sculpt tool mode this happened:

[image]

I don't know what to do or how to fix this. I just want my characters hair to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this you could add a subdivision surface modifier and use that with the smooth sculpt tool to keep things without all of those bumps. Make sure that your head is rounded ish to keep the subdivision surface working. I did the same with a hair model and it worked for me. try giving it a shot.

Comment: Thanks but it's still not really giving me the look i want. 
http://puu.sh/ADvHC/cd2b64d12d.png
As you can see, it's not choppy. It's more rounded for some reason. I can't figure out how to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you do a bit more of a roundabout view so its possible to see more of what's going on?